# WPF Tooltip Visibility

Tags: wpf, binding, tooltip, visibility

How can I ensure that a button's Tooltip is only visible when the button is disabled?

What can I bind the tooltip's visibility to?

Comment: When it "IS" disabled? - did you mean "is not" disabled?

Comment: It might make sense to display a tooltip describing why you can't touch this button.  If that is David's intent, I think it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Yeah, i guess so, i wasn't being picky. I was just genuinely interested :)

Comment: I did mean IS disabled. As reuscam suggested, the tooltip is to explain why the button is disabled.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You will need to set [ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.showondisabled.aspx) to True on the Button in order to have the Tooltip visible at all when the Button is disabled.  You can bind [ToolTipService.IsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.isenabled.aspx) on the Button to enable and disable the Tooltip.

Comment: For anyone who wants to do the same things as me, I've posted the full xaml for the button as an answer.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 37):

This is the full XAML of the Button (based on the answer of @Quartermeister)

```
<Button 
  x:Name="btnAdd" 
  Content="Add" 
  ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" 
  ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=btnAdd, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource boolToOppositeBoolConverter}}" 
  ToolTip="Appointments cannot be added whilst the event has outstanding changes."/>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do it using a simple trigger also. Just place the following piece of code into a Window.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <CheckBox Name="chkDisabler" Content="Enable / disable button" Margin="10" />
    <Button Content="Hit me" Width="200" Height="100" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkDisabler, Path=IsChecked}">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Hi, there! I'm disabled!" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This was handy to see the syntax for setting the `ShowOnDisabled` via a `Style` setter.

Comment: If I interpret this code correctly, one can set two triggers to deliver two different tooltips, one for button disabled and one for enabled?

Comment: Yes Mike, You could add a second trigger for IsEnabled and True for that.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly modified answer for what David Ward has proposed. Here is the full code

Add a value converter to resouces like this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Converters:NegateConverter x:Key="negateConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then define following xaml

```
<Button 
  x:Name="btnAdd" 
  Content="Add" 
  ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" 
  ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource negateConverter}}" 
  ToolTip="Hi guys this is the tool tip"/>
```

The value converter looks like this

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(bool))]
  public class NegateConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
     return  !((bool)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```