# wpf: how to show tooltip when button disabled by command?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to show a tooltip regardless of a buttons state, but this does not seem to do the trick:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=CommandExecuteAction}" 
        ToolTip="{Binding Path=Description}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="true"
        Style="{StaticResource toolbarButton}">
   <Image Source="{Binding Path=Icon}"></Image>
</Button>
```

How can i show the tooltip when the button is disabled due to command.CanExecute returning false?

**Note:**

ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="true" works like a charm. The reason this didn't work in my example is because the style associated with the button redefines the controltemplate and turned off hit-testing on the button when the button was disabled (IsHitTestVisible=false). Re-enabling hit-testing in the controltemplate made the tooltip appear when the button was disabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Tooltip Visibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149016/wpf-tooltip-visibility)

Comment: I'm using the ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled, but its not working.

Comment: Just delete this question. I did a small test project and ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled works just fine.

Comment: I'm glad this question didn't get deleted. It quickly and accurately answered a question/problem I had, which is the exact reason I come to SO in the first place. Thanks for being Lazy(tm) Marius. :-)

Comment: Excuse me, is there a way I can show it only when disabled?

Comment: @advapi Try assigning the Tooltip text only when control is disabled, otherwise set empty Tooltip.

Answer (score 373, accepted):

You can use on xaml element directly:

```xml
<Grid ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" ... >
```

Comment: MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.aspx

Comment: This goes in the xaml declaration for the object on which the tooltip will appear, i.e.:
`<Button  ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True">...`

Comment: If someone finds this now, Visual Studios updated this API. It is now: ToolTipService.SetShowOnDisabled. The first parameter takes in the DependencyObject (i.e, your button and such) and the second parameter is a bool.

Comment: @user2529011 Visual Studio? Or are we talking .NET (Core)? I don't get how a visual studio API is going to effect anything aside from VS extensions or plugins...

Answer (score 41):

This is a good method to add to your startup code:

```
ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabledProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(FrameworkElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));
```

It ensures that for any class inheriting from `FrameworkElement`, tooltips are shown even if a control instance is disabled. This covers all elements that can have a tooltip.

Comment: Can you explain what this does? Saying it's a good method at startup doesn't explain.

Comment: It ensures that for any class inheriting from Control, tooltips are shown even if Control instance is disabled

Comment: It is ironic that users have the greatest need for the tooltip *when* the control is disabled, as they want to know *why* the control is disabled. This is a good example of a default in WPF that is incorrect the vast majority of the time. So it's worth changing it.

Comment: Edited to use *typeof (FrameworkElement)* rather than *typeof(Control)* as this covers all elements that can have a tooltip.

Answer (score 7):

Make tooltip visible for ALL disabled Buttons and Checkboxes:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="true"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="true"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The `BasedOn=...` prevents that you lose any other styles that have been applied to checkbox or button before. If you don't use any other styles for button or checkbox you can remove the `BasedOn=..` parts.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone want to do it programmatically behind the code. It works on any element, not just `Button`:

```
Button button = new Button()
{
    Content = "Hello world",
    ToolTip = "You can show tooltip even when the button is disabled",
    IsEnabled = false
};

ToolTipService.SetShowOnDisabled(button, true);
```