# how to show tooltip over disbabled button in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp

how to show tooltip over disabled button in UWP?

```
Button b=new button();
b.IsEnabled=false;
b.content="Button";
ToolTip t= new ToolTip();
t.Content="Hello";
ToolTipService.SetToolTip(b, ToolTip);
```

Comment: The Button is disabled... Why would you want to show a tool tip?

Comment: even it is disabled ,i want to show the purpose of button in tooltip?

Comment: [Here is how to do the same thing in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153539/wpf-how-to-show-tooltip-when-button-disabled-by-command). Perhaps the same solution is applicable?

Comment: ShowOnDisabled property  was not present in UWP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling a button not only changes the style, but also intercepts the triggering of related events.

For example, if disabled, Button will not trigger `Pointer` related events. The display condition of the `Tooltip` is that the `Pointer` is hovering on the control for a period of time. If the control cannot detect the `Pointer` event, the `Tooltip` will never meet the corresponding trigger.

But if you need it to display, we can change it another way:

```cs
var grid = new Grid();
Button b = new Button();
b.IsEnabled = false;
b.Content = "Button";
ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
t.Content = "Hello";
grid.Children.Add(b);
ToolTipService.SetToolTip(grid, t);
```

We can put `Tooltip` on the `Grid` that will not be disabled, this can avoid this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: its working fine,but it increase the memory..is there any other way ??

Comment: A simple Button cannot achieve the functions you need (you cannot display Tooltip once it is disabled). If you think that the Grid is expensive, you can switch to other controls, but the idea is the same.

Comment: The proposed solution by wrapping the disabled Button in a Grid didn't work for me on WinUI 3. The tooltip text did not appear when hovering over with the mouse.
I did manage to get it working though by setting <Grid Background="Transparent">.

Comment: How utterly bizarre that setting the grid's background to Transparent makes this work, but the same fix worked for me.