# Expander.Header ToolTip active even with Expander.IsEnabled=false

Tags: wpf, tooltip, expander

If the Expander.IsEnabled=false then the tooltip on the header is not active.
Is there a way to have a ToolTip even if Expander.IsEnabled=false?

```
 <Expander.Header>
      <TextBlock Text="Export" ToolTip="ToolTip - I don't show up if Expander.IsEnabled=false" 
                 Style="{StaticResource TabItemHeaderSemiBold11}"/>
 </Expander.Header>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149016/wpf-tooltip-visibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"`:

```
<Expander IsEnabled="False">
    <Expander.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Export" ToolTip="ToolTip - I don't show up if Expander.IsEnabled=false"
                ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"/>
    </Expander.Header>
</Expander>
```

Comment: What is the point of posting an answer to a duplicate question?

Comment: @Versatile points. and to prevent people having to visit another url for an answer that could be easily left here until duplicates are handled.