# Tooltip is not visible on the disabled checkbox wpf

Tags: wpf, checkbox, tooltip

Tooltip is not visible on disabled checkbox even after setting ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True".

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TaskCompletionVisbilityConverter},ConverterParameter='chkbox'}" 
                             Height="16" Width="16" Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TaskColorConverter}}"
                               ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" ToolTipService.IsEnabled="True"
                              ToolTip="Check To complete Task"
                               IsEnabled="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource EnableDisableConverter},
                        ConverterParameter='checkbox',Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="37,5,0,0">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Tooltip Visibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149016/wpf-tooltip-visibility)

Comment: I do not think this question is a duplicate of [WPF Tooltip Visibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149016/wpf-tooltip-visibility). Indeed @Pa1 already uses `ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"` and `ToolTipService.IsEnabled="True"`. I guess the tooltip should be visible, so maybe there is something else which hides it. Pa1, can you provide more details about your XAML?

Answer (score 11):

Your code works for me.  `ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"` should be what you need.

Please check that you haven't set `IsHitTestVisible` to `false` in any Style/ControlTemplate associated with the checkbox.

Setting `IsHitTestVisible` to `false` means that it will ignore any mouse events associated with the control and so you won't get the tooltip.

Comment: I removed all the IsHitTestVisible  reference from my style but still didnt get

Comment: So the tooltip does display when the checkbox is enabled, but when it is disabled it won't display?  Try listening to the `MouseOver` event to check that this is still being fired when the checkbox is disabled?

Answer (score 3):

`ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"` was not working for me. Below works :

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style>                                     
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True" />
    </Style>                                 
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
```