# Getting values for disabled button for Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#

I would like to create a tooltip to user informing them why the button will be disabled.
However, the program didn't detected any MouseEvent when I hoevr the mouse on it.

How can I do?

Thanks

I would like to create a tooltip to user informing them why the button will be disabled. However, the program didn't detected any MouseEvent when I hoevr the mouse on it.

How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: When you are told that you need to add more text to your question, it's because no good question can be asked with as little text as you have provided. Simply copying and pasting the text you already have is showing clear disrespect for the system and the people you expect to use it to help you. Provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, which must include what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You might also try adding all the relevant tags, as we have no idea what type of app this is. Answers may differ for WinForms, WPF, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the button is disabled, it will not generate mouse events.
There is a simple trick to accomplish what you want:

Place the button in a container-control which is marginally larger than the button (e.g. a panel) and attach the tooltip to this control.
When enabling the button, you disable the tooltip. When disabling the button you activate the tooltip.

A small example using winforms :

[image]

where the button is placed inside `panel1` and a 'tooltip1' is attached to that panel with text 'Button Disabled'.

In the event handler for the checkbox you change the state of both the button and the tooltip:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        toolTip1.Active = false;
        return;
    }
    button1.Enabled = false;
    toolTip1.Active = true;
}
```

The same mechanism will work in WPF as well. Here an invisible border is used as container:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="294" Width="413">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

    <CheckBox Content="Button Enabled" Click="CheckBox_Changed"  Margin="20" />
    <Border x:Name ="border1" BorderThickness="0"  Height="40" Padding="10" Width="220" >
        <Border.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock>Button.Disabled</TextBlock>
        </Border.ToolTip>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="button1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width ="200" IsEnabled= "False"  />
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

With the code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    TextBlock buttonTooltip = new TextBlock { Text = "Button Disabled."}; 

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   
    private void CheckBox_Changed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
        var tooltip = border1.ToolTip as TextBlock;
        if (checkBox.IsChecked ?? false)
        {
            button1.IsEnabled = true;
            border1.ToolTip = null;
            return;
        }
        button1.IsEnabled = false;
        border1.ToolTip = buttonTooltip;
    }
}
```

Update: The OP's question is better solved in the link provided by ASh below. Still the technique shown here can be usefull in other situations where you need to process input events on a control that does not provide them itself.

Comment: even simpler trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149016/wpf-tooltip-visibility